# MP Android is not showing X axis value

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

[Bar Graph with NO X value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P6EQ.png)I am able to plot MP Android chart successfully but If I click the particular bar then its not showing the X axis value. I am using kotlin and below is the part of the sample code.

Input:

[{"date":"2018-09-15","count":"5"},{"date":"2018-09-16","count":"10"}]

Working Code:

```
val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    val labels = ArrayList<String>()
    val arr = JSONArray(jsonStringArray)
    for (i in 0 until arr.length()) {
        entries.add(BarEntry(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("count").toFloat(), i))
        labels.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"))
           }
    val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Test Data")
    barDataSet.setValueTextSize(10f)
    val data = BarData(labels, barDataSet)
    barChart.data = data 
    val colors = intArrayOf(Color.rgb(132, 101, 122))
    barDataSet.setColors(colors)
```

Comment: Do you mean X axis value or Y axis value? X axis value should be shown below the axis automatically when there is enough space.

Comment: Thanks @RickyMo for your response. If I point to the bar then I want the value to be displayed at the top.

Comment: I added Sample Bar Chart in this discussion.

Comment: That is the Y value not the X.

Comment: That's right. If I click one bar then I can see only Y value but not the X Value. My goal here is to If I click the bar then I need to see both the X and Y values.

Comment: You can use `barDataSet.setValueFormatter()` and implement your custom `ValueFormatter` to show whatever text you want.

Comment: I tried ValueFormatter, Its rounding the Y value but its not showing X value in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `ValueFormatter` to show whatever text you want. In `getFormattedValue()`, you get access to `entry` which you can call `getXIndex()`

```
private class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter
{

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return String.format("%d,%f",entry.getXIndex(),value);
    }
}
```

In kotlin you can do it like this:

```
barDataSet.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter{
    fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, entry: Entry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler): String {
        return String.format("%d,%f", entry.xIndex, value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Below is the sample code. Somehow the formatter is not working properly for me.                         [{"date":"2018-09-15","count":"5"},{"date":"2018-09-16","price":"10"}]
  
  val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        val labels = ArrayList<String>()
        val arr = JSONArray(jsonStringArray)
        for (i in 0 until arr.length()) {
            entries.add(BarEntry(arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("count").toFloat(), i))
            labels.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("date"))
               }

Comment: Please add your relevant code in your post properly.

Comment: sorry about it. Added the complete code in the post.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of your `ValueFormatter` and the complete initialization of your bar chart?

Comment: barDataSet.valueFormatter   ----I am using Kotlin

Comment: Please show your code. You should have created a class like `class MyValueFormatter : ValueFormatter` and do `barDataSet.valueFormatter = MyValueFormatter()` somewhere.

Comment: I am getting data from the JSON output and the complete code is in the post. var jsonStringArray="[{"date":"2018-09-15","count":"5"},{"date":"2018-09-16","count":"10"}]"

Comment: You didn't show your implementation of `ValueFormatter`. I added kotlin code to do so.

Comment: Thanks but now its showing 25*value with six digits of zero after the value. I am not sure how its getting the value. barDataSet.valueFormatter= ValueFormatter { value, entry, dataSetIndex, viewPortHandler -> String.format("%d,%f", entry.xIndex, value) }